# Adding a link button in the footer of WebGrid Mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcgrid

I have inserted the link buttons "Add New Record" and "Save All" at the bottom of my Webgrid. But I want them to be in the footer of the `WebGrid`. I have searched for this a lot, but found nothing. Can someone tell me how to add a link or button in the "footer" of a `WebGrid`.

Here is some code of my `WebGrid`

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcGrid2.Models.Employee>
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(
    source: Model,
    rowsPerPage: 4);

}

@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "WebGrid1" },
        tableStyle:"gridTable",
        headerStyle: "gridHead",
        footerStyle: "gridFooter",
        rowStyle: "gridRow",
        alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        firstText: "<<",
        previousText: "<",
        nextText: ">",
        lastText: ">>",
        columns: grid.Columns(        
                               @* grid.Column( columnName : "EmployeeId", 
                                            format: @<text>@item.EmpId</text>),*@

                                grid.Column(columnName: "Employee Id",
                                            format: @<span> 
                                                        <span id="spanEmpId_@(item.EmpId)">@item.EmpId</span> 
                                                         @Html.TextBox("EmpId_" + (int)item.EmpId, (int)item.EmpId, new { @style = "display:none" })
                                                   </span>),

                                 grid.Column(columnName: "Employee Name",
                                           format: @<span> 
                                                       <span id="spanEmpName_@(item.EmpId)">@item.EmpName</span> 
                                                       @Html.TextBox("EmpName_" + (int)item.EmpId, (string)item.EmpName, new { @style = "display:none" })
                                                   </span>),

                                 grid.Column(columnName: "Designation",
                                             format: @<span> 
                                                        <span id="spanEmpDesg_@(item.EmpId)" >@item.Designation</span> 
                                                         @Html.TextBox("EmpDesg_" + (int)item.EmpId, (string)item.Designation, new { @style = "display:none" })
                                                     </span>),

                                grid.Column(columnName: "Action", 
                                            format: @<text>                     
                                                        <a href="#" id="Edit_@(item.EmpId)" class="edit">Edit</a>
                                                        <a href="#" id="Update_@(item.EmpId)" style="display:none" class="update">Update</a>
                                                        <a href="#" id="Cancel_@(item.EmpId)" style="display:none"  class="cancel">Cancel</a>
                                                         <a href="#" id="Save_@(item.EmpId)" style="display:none" class="save">Update</a>
                                                        <a href="#" id="iCancel_@(item.EmpId)" style="display:none"  class="icancel">Cancel</a>
                                                        <a href="#" id="Delete_@(item.EmpId)"  class="delete">Delete</a>
                                                    </text>)


                            ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebGrid doesn't have a modifiable footer per se. However if you view the [tutorial on ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrebaltieri/archive/2010/11/02/asp-net-mvc-3-working-with-webgrid-part-2.aspx) you'll see a way to make that happen in css.

What you can do is make your last row the same css class as your footer, or you can insert your buttons/links with javascript. Neither approach is clean, but as far as I can tell there is not a better way to accomplish your goal without rewriting the control. Many people have suggested looking into Telerik's controls, if you have/can get a license for their stuff.

Comment: Webgrid have the footer and I have already gone through that tutorial. In that there is nothing to add a control in the footer.

Comment: Clarified my answer a bit for you.